# ngx-admin mascara con cantidad de caracteres dinamico

Tags: javascript, angular, regex, angular5, angular7

Estimado,

Estoy intentando realizar mediante la libreria de ngx-mask que el input no acepte cierto caracteres, para eso aplica [patterns] pero el no me funciona si obligatoriamente debo tener la mascara "mask".

El input debe guardar un nombre de hasta 200 caracteres y alli es donde viene mi dificultad.

**Componente html:**

```
<input type="text" mask="00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" [patterns]="customPatterns" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9^-_-.()*!{}]">
```

**Componente ts:**

```
public customPatterns = {
    '0': { pattern: new RegExp('[a-zA-Z0-9^-_-.()*!{}]') }
  };
```

Con el codigo que les acabo de mostrar me funciona pero la mascara lo coloco los 200 caracteres que tiene que validar, cuando el input va colocar menos de 200 caracteres el reclama porque obligatoriamente debo colocar 200 caracteres.

Por favor necesito un apoyo en eso ya sea validar por el ngx-mask o por otro metodo como una funcion en onChange u otro cosa.

Answer (score 0):

Usa un asterisco para repetir el patrón y agrega el atributo `maxlength`:

```
<input type="text" mask="0*" maxlength="200" [patterns]="customPatterns"/>
```

Comment: No funciono, lo solucione de esta forma `<input type="text" mask="A*" maxlength="200" [validate]="false" [patterns]="customPatterns"/>`